# Changing the value of a repeating item in an array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array

```
`array(
   [0] =>array(
     [id] => 1,
     [item] => ring,
     [total] => 1000
   ),
   [1] =>array(
     [id] => 1,
     [item] => book,
     [total] => 1000
   ),
   [2] =>array(
     [id] => 1,
     [item] => pen,
     [total] => 400
   )
);`
```

I need result when `[id]` is same value only first to show `[total]` and other need to show  `-` like below please.

```
 `array(
  [0] =>array(
     [id] => 1,
     [item] => ring,
     [total] => 1000
   ),
  [1] =>array(
     [id] => 1,
     [item] => book,
     [total] => -
   ),
  [2] =>array(
     [id] => 1,
     [item] => pen,
     [total] => 400
   )
  );`
```

Thank you for help please.

Comment: The same with the previeus element you mean? Or the first element of the array? What have you done so far?

Comment: sorry my miss take at 
[2] =>array(
     [id] => 2,
     [item] => pen,
     [total] => 400
   )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script might help you to do so:

```
$arr = [
    "0" => [
        "id" => "1",
        "item" => "ring",
        "total" => "1000",
    ],
    "1" => [
        "id" => "1",
        "item" => "book",
        "total" => "1000",
    ],
    "2" => [
        "id" => "1",
        "item" => "pen",
        "total" => "400",
    ],
    "3" => [
        "id" => "1",
        "item" => "pen",
        "total" => "400",
    ],
    "4" => [
        "id" => "1",
        "item" => "pen",
        "total" => "400",
    ],
    "5" => [
        "id" => "1",
        "item" => "pen",
        "total" => "500",
    ],
    "6" => [
        "id" => "1",
        "item" => "ring",
        "total" => "1000",
    ],
];

$out_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    array_push($out_arr, $value);
    if ($arr[(int) $key + 1]["total"] && $arr[(int) $key + 1]["id"]) {
        foreach ($arr as $key2 => $value2) {
            if ($value["id"] == $arr[(int) $key2 + 1]["id"] && $value2["total"] == $arr[(int) $key2 + 1]["total"]) {
                $arr[(int) $key + 1]["total"] = '-';
            }
        }

    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

#### Output

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["item"]=>
    string(4) "ring"
    ["total"]=>
    string(4) "1000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["item"]=>
    string(4) "book"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "-"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["item"]=>
    string(3) "pen"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "-"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["item"]=>
    string(3) "pen"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "-"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["item"]=>
    string(3) "pen"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "-"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["item"]=>
    string(3) "pen"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "-"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["item"]=>
    string(4) "ring"
    ["total"]=>
    string(1) "-"
  }
}
```

Comment: excuse me @ line if ($value["id"] == $arr[(int) $key + 1]["id"] && $value["total"] == $arr[(int) $key + 1]["total"]) { $arr[(int) $key + 1]["total"] = '-'; } $key+1 Is "Undefined offset: 3" i think index 3 Undefined sir.

Comment: your old code it's work just add `isset` for check array before `if ($arr` Thank you for solve @Emma (^^) You safe my time.